# Cartesian product on same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to translate a R code in SQL Query.

```
tab1 <- merge(tab1, tab1, by='col1', allow.cartesian = T)
tab1 <- tab1[col2.x != col2.y,]
```

I have to do a cartesian product on same table, based on key **col1** column.

This is my situation:

```
col1 | col2
 a   |  b 
 a   |  c 
 a   |  d 
 c   |  e 
 c   |  f 
 g   |  i 
 h   |  j
```

and I'm trying to get something like this:

```
col1 | col2 | col3
 a   |  b   |  c
 a   |  b   |  d
 a   |  c   |  b
 a   |  c   |  d
 a   |  d   |  b
 a   |  d   |  c
 c   |  e   |  f
 c   |  f   |  e
```

so I did a query like this:

```
SELECT a.*, b.col2 as col3
FROM tab1 a
JOIN tab1 b on 
 a.col1 = b.col1 AND 
 a.col2 <> b.col2
```

The query works, but it's really really slow compared to R. The result it's correct but with **col3** different order:

```
col1 | col2 | col3
 a   |  b   |  d
 a   |  b   |  c
 a   |  c   |  d
 a   |  c   |  b
 a   |  d   |  c
 a   |  d   |  b
 c   |  e   |  f
 c   |  f   |  e
```

Is this the only way to do this? And also there is a way to increment the performarces?
I have a table with like 2M rows, and with the cartesian I get like 20M rows.

In R it takes like 1 or 2 minutes to get the result, on PostgreSQL it takes like 10-15 minutes.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Does your table have index on both columns?

Comment: No because this table it is a CTE and so I dont think those fields can be indexed.

Comment: It would help to have the EXPLAIN of your CTE query and the JOIN query. Why not making a MATERIALIZED VIEW for the CTE? It allows indexation as well.

Comment: I tried in this way, with MATERIALIZED VIEW and Index and it works as expected! Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. Would you mind add an answer to this post showing how you solve your issue. At the very moment you are the only one who benefit from time other users spent trying to solve your issue. An hoc problem statement (original post) and answers are valuable to the whole community. I'll to vote for your question and your answer when they are updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the @jlandercy and @Edouard suggestions, I solved the problem creating a MATERIALIZED VIEW and an INDEX with the columns.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW tab1_mat AS
SELECT *
FROM tab1

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS col1_col2 ON tab1 USING BTREE (col1, col2) ;
```

After this, I'm able to do my query:

```
SELECT a.*, b.col2 as col3
FROM tab1_mat a
JOIN tab1_mat b on 
 a.col1 = b.col1 AND 
 a.col2 <> b.col2
```

Then I scheduled a job that every night updates my materialized view using this command.

```
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW tab1_mat;
```

Answer (score 1):

*"The result it's correct but with col3 different order"*

To get the right order, you have to add the `ORDER BY 1,2,3` clause to your self-joined query, but this is going to make it even slower ...

*"there is a way to increment the performances ?"*

Yes if you don't have yet created the following index, it should dramatically accelerate your self-joined query :

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS col1_col2 ON tab1 USING BTREE (col1, col2) ;
```

Comment: Yes I tried to create an index, but I'm using a CTE and so it's not possible.

Comment: Your cte relies on tables so that we can have a deeper look if you share the exact definition of the cte.