# Do checkup on columns before crosstab in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, crosstab

So im working on a very complex query. In the end the enduser should be able to pass a parameter p_e_id over the gui and get the result as return.

Goal is sum total over years on ref and compare two years with another and then return the rows where the difference in % is over 20%.

```
CREATE TABLE t1(id integer primary key, ref integer,v_id integer,e_id integer, street text, city text, total integer, year integer) ;
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES

(1,  2077,15,1,'Burban Str.','London',  11000,   2019),
(2,  2077,15,1,'Burban Str.','London',  13000,   2020),
(3,  1000,20,1,'Ocean road','London',  10000,   2019),
(4,  1000,20,1,'Ocean road','London',  12000,   2020),
(5,  2000,30,1,'City Str.','Manchester',  500, 2019),
(6,  2000,30,1,'City Str.','Manchester',  800, 2020),
(7,  2020,50,2,'Post Str.','NY',  300, 2019),
(8,  2020,50,2,'Post Str.','NY',  700, 2020);
```

Creating the function for the input parameter and also making it possible to call the function inside of the crosstab in the next step. If i don't make a function and uses cte's the crosstab can't find the cte's Table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function(p_e_id integer)
 RETURNS TABLE(id integer, ref integer,v_id integer,e_id integer, street text, city text, total integer, year integer)
 LANGUAGE sql
 IMMUTABLE
AS $function$
select * from t1 where t1.e_id = p_e_id
$function$;
```

So here is the tricky part: I always want to compare two years with each other. In this case 2020 and 2019. But the years in the t1 table changes and sometime i maybe have to compare 2001 with 2000 and next time 2022 with 2021. It will never be more than two years to compare in the table so i need to find a way to catch the years i need and saved them in some parameter before i come to the step with crosstab. Here i don't want to hardcode like 50 years to cover everything and get an output with nulls.

```
with crosstab as (
select * from 
crosstab
('select ref,v_id,street,city,year,total from test_function(1) order by 1,4',
$$values ('2017'::text),('2018'::text),('2019'::text),('2020'::text)$$
)
as ct  (ref int,v_id int,street text,city text,"2017" numeric,"2018" numeric,"2019" numeric,"2020" numeric)
)

    select * from (
    select ref , v_id , 
    street ,city,"2020","2019", trunc((nullif("2020",0)-nullif("2019",0))/nullif("2019",0) * 100,2) as diff from crosstab 
    )x 
    where x.diff >= 20 or x.diff <= -20
```

Is there some possible way to find out that in this case i will be working with 2019 and 2020 and then do something like this?

```
    with crosstab as (
    select * from 
    crosstab
    ('select ref,v_id,street,city,year,total from test_function(1) order by 1,4',
    $$values ('2019'::text),('2020'::text)$$
    )
    as ct  (ref int,v_id int,street text,city text,"2019" numeric,"2020" numeric)
    )

select * from (
select ref , v_id , 
street ,city,"2020","2019", trunc((nullif("2020",0)-nullif("2019",0))/nullif("2019",0) * 100,2) as diff from crosstab 
)x 
where x.diff >= 20 or x.diff <= -20
```

[Here is a demo where i get the wished output but with hardcoded years](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=bf0b8bb624e20f59529d9706897636c6)

Answer (score 0):

Naming dynamically the columns of a query's result in postgres is not obvious.
Here is a full-dynamic solution based on a user-defined `composite type` and the standard jsonb function `jsonb_populate_record` :

First we create dynamically the composite type which correspond to a specific year with a function instead of a procedure which doesn't exist yet in pg10 :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION composite_type(_year integer)
RETURNS void LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'DROP TYPE IF EXISTS ' || quote_ident(_year :: text) ; 
  EXECUTE 'CREATE TYPE ' || quote_ident(_year :: text) || ' AS (ref integer, street text, city text, ' || quote_ident(_year :: text) || ' integer, ' || quote_ident((_year - 1) :: text) || ' integer, difference integer)' ;
END ;
$$ ;
```

Then we create the generic function `test` and which implements a dynamic query returning a jsonb object :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(_year integer)
RETURNS setof jsonb LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
   'SELECT to_jsonb(t.*)
      FROM 
         ( SELECT ref, street, city
                , (array_agg(total ORDER BY year))[2] AS ' || quote_ident(_year :: text) || '
                , (array_agg(total ORDER BY year))[1] AS ' || quote_ident((_year - 1) :: text) || '
                , trunc(100*((array_agg(total ORDER BY year))[2] - (array_agg(total ORDER BY year))[1])/(array_agg(total ORDER BY year))[1] :: numeric, 2) AS difference
             FROM t1
            WHERE year BETWEEN ' || quote_nullable((_year - 1) :: text) || ' AND ' || quote_nullable(_year :: text) || '
            GROUP BY ref, street, city
         ) AS t
     WHERE abs(t.difference) >= 20' ;
END ;
$$ ;
```

Finally, we can call the function `composite_type` and then the function `test` with the expected input parameter `year` :

```
SELECT composite_type(2020) ;
SELECT (jsonb_populate_record(NULL :: "2020", t.data)).*
  FROM test(2020) AS t(data) ;
```

see the result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=81ad6d4982ebdce68e2d2f2f3e62310e).

Comment: Hello @edouard! In the end all i want is to call i function and pass a parameter p_v_id. I can't pass a year since i don't know the years. To know which years i need i have to scan the test_function on distinct years or something.